# how to use vue-router + inertia

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, inertiajs, laravel-10

hello guys i have **laravel**and **vue 3** application and i use **inertia** for glues the server side and client side.
i have nested component **user** inside **home.vue** page
i wanna customize     `user/{id}/` route to user component by vue-router

try use vue-router children property i get 404 not found page
this is code

*\resources\js\router\index.js*

```
path: "/User/Home",
name: "create",
component:() => import('@/create'),
```

*/routes\web.php*

```
Route::get('/user/home', function () {
    return Inertia::render('User/Home');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because Inertia is server-side rendering instead of client-side. to make this work (I had to found this out too, it's documented pretty poorly) - on the route where you are serving the template, you need to add a catch-all on all the endpoints.

it looks a bit like this:

```
Route::get('my/route/{any?}', 'InertiaController@index')
->where('any', '.*')
->name('my-spa-route');
```

I am not a pro, but basically you need to catch all the endpoints AFTER your initial route, to serve the same template, vue-router uses BrowserHistoryAPI which is client-side, Inertia is server-side. It will serve a 404 because technically for inertia /user/{id} is an endpoint that expects a template.

What you do in this technique, is basically passing along route handling from inertia to vue-router.

Alternatively, you can configure vue-router to use Hash History mode (read about it in their [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html))

But try to think if Inertia is what you need here. Vue-Router and Inertia router are two different things. I would recommend trying to handle the user route with inertia, since they don't play nicely together according to my own experience.

Comment: Thank you, bruh. I honestly couldn't find an alternative for "vue-router" that would allow me to create a path to nested component.